# Неправильное преобразование символов UTF-8 в линуксе

Tags: java, linux, utf-8, unicode

Есть проект (backend) написанный на Java 1.8. на **frontend(node.js, angular)** есть функция чтения информации через upload простых txt файлов, которые содержат буквы в кодировке **UTF** (ü, ç, ş, ğ, ə и т.д.). в backend информация приходит в виде строки, который преобразуется в byte[].

В другом классе специальный метод обратно преобразует байты в строку в формате **UTF-8** и выдает пользователю всю информацию в таблице в браузере. проблема в том, что на локальной системе (*Windows 10*) все работает нормально и после всех операции пользователь видит нормальные данные, но после того как я деплою проект на сервер (*RedHat*), то там уже вместо символов видны вопросительные знаки. что самое интересное, когда я делаю debug, то в информационном окне дебага я тоже вижу вопросительные знаки.

Но в браузере все ок. перепробовал все возможности перекодировки, но не могу понять где запинка и с какого моменты происходит развал символов. может кто-то встречался с подобным? вот куски кода чтения строк от фронтенда и их преобразование:

```
List<byte[]> binaryFiles = new ArrayList<>();
if (batchFiles != null && batchFiles.getFiles() != null) {
    for (String file : batchFiles.getFiles()) {
        byte[] fileBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(file);
        binaryFiles.add(fileBytes);
    }
}
```

а тут я байты обратно преобразую в строки:

```
for (byte[] value : file) {
   try {
      Charset.availableCharsets().get("UTF-8").newDecoder().decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(value));
      decodedString += new String(new String(value).getBytes("8859_1"), Charset.forName("utf8"));
   } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
       decodedString += new String(value, Charset.forName("cp866"));
   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(AllotmentItem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Консоль точно поддерживает UTF-8? Попробуйте вывести cat'ом файл с кириллицей и посмотрите на результат

Comment: @tutankhamun консоль поддерживает. но проблема ведь в показе данных в браузере пользователя после деплоя проекта на линукс. когда работаю в на локальной виндовс системе, таких проблем нет

Comment: Тогда не очень понимаю вот этот момент: "...тоже вижу вопросительные знаки. но в браузере все ок"

Comment: @tutankhamun имеется ввиду, что во время дебага в Netbeans, я вопросительные знаки вижу в окне дебага, в параметрах. т.е. по идее в таком случае они и в браузере моем должны выходить с вопросительными знаками, но на выходе я получаю нормальный текст

Comment: конструктор `String(byte[])` использует кодировку `Charset.defaultCharset()` она скорее всего разная на windows и linux. Вообще, зачем у вас так наворочено все? Ну допустим первая строка проверяет, что `value` можно без ошибок раскодировать в utf8 (иначе будет исключение). Дальше вы получаете из них строку, используя системную кодировку, кодируете ее в байты в `latin-1`, и делаете новую строку, как будто в этих байтах utf8. Я не уверен, что что-то кроме ascii вообще сможет пережить такую трансформацию.

Comment: Если честно, я абсолютно не знаком я java, но меня смущает упоминание 8859_1. Если это кодировка iso 8859-1, то в ней в принципе нет кириллических символов. Если смесь символов перекодировать в неё, а потом в UTF8, то вместо кириллицы будут кракозябры.